# How to add to the existing row?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, windows-server-2012

I am doing a trigger in t-sql which will keep 'budget' table up-to-date after every INSERT, UPDATE or DELETE statement.
To insert information on budget table I use this:

```
INSERT INTO budget (value) SELECT SUM(sal) FROM emp
```

I delete each time the table to hold only 1 record (the same thing I want to do on my trigger.

Here's the code of my trigger:

```
DROP TRIGGER licznik
go
CREATE TRIGGER licznik ON emp
    FOR INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE
AS
    DELETE  FROM budget
    DECLARE @sal_new INT ,
        @sal_old INT
    SELECT  @sal_new = sal
    FROM    inserted
    SELECT  @sal_old = sal
    FROM    deleted
    PRINT @sal_new
    IF @sal_new > 0 
        BEGIN
            UPDATE  budget
            SET     value = value + @sal_new
        END
    IF @sal_old > 0 
        BEGIN
            UPDATE  budget
            SET     value = value - @sal_old
        END
    SET @sal_new = 0
    SET @sal_old = 0
```

The trigger shouldn't compute entire budget from the begining, but increase or decrease the budget basing on changes in EMP table - that's why i am updating the row. Unfortunately it doesn't work at all.

How to solve this problem?

Comment: The first command of the trigger is a delete from budget, so budget has no rows after that.   Then you try to update budget.   What do you think is there to update?   You just emptied the table with the delete.

Comment: Why don't you do this in a view?

Comment: I would just create a view that does that.  Are you doing this for performance reasons?  Thing is the trigger is going to have overhead.

Comment: `inserted` and `deleted` are tables so that they can represent the results of set operations. Designing a trigger on the assumption that they will always process exactly one row is generally a bad plan. If you are absolutely certain there will never be more than one row then _please_ add a check for the number of rows and use `RaIsError` or `Throw` to explicitly inform those who come along later that they have attempted to execute an unacceptable statement. (`if ( select Count(*) from inserted ) > 1 RaIsError( 'FooTable_Insert: No more than one row may be processed.', 25, 42 ) with log`)

Comment: Are you sure that you don't want to update the budget based on the _change_ in `sal`, e.g. `update Budget set Value += Coalesce( @Sal_New, 0 ) - Coalesce( @Sal_Old, 0 );`?

Comment: Your trigger has a MAJOR flaw. It assumes there will only ever be a single row in the operation. This is not how triggers work in sql server. They fire once per operation. When you see scalar variables in a trigger it is a clear sign the trigger is not set based and needs a total rewrite.

Answer (score 1):

```
create view BudgetView as

SELECT SUM(sal) FROM emp
```

Unless emp is just enourmous that view is going to be fast
Those triggers add a lot of overhead to emp

Answer (score 0):

This will handle set operations and update the budget accordingly:

```
create trigger licznik on emp
for insert, update, delete
as
-- Make sure that there is a budget row to update.
if not exists ( select 42 from Budget )
  insert into Budget ( Value ) values ( 0 );
-- Get the total of the adjustments.
declare @DeletedSum as Int;
declare @InsertedSum as Int;
select @DeletedSum = sum( Sal ) from deleted;
select @InsertedSum = sum( Sal ) from inserted;
-- Update the budget.
update Budget
  set Value += Coalesce( @InsertedSum, 0 ) - Coalesce( @DeletedSum, 0 );
```